# Reading specific character columns from text file

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net

Using c# If I had data that looks like this:

```
123456 CUSTOMER      ADDRESS CITY STATE
123457 CUSTOMER ABC  ADDRESS CITY STATE
123458 CUSTOMER 1234 ADDRESS CITY STATE
```

For each row, how can I read characters one through 1-6 if I know that is the customers ID and 8-20 if I know that's the customers name?  I'm looking to then take the data (For each line) and create a new datarow in a datatable.

Here is the code for my datatable:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

DataColumn CUST_ID = new DataColumn();
CUST_ID.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
CUST_ID.ColumnName = "CUST_ID";

DataColumn CUST_DESC = new DataColumn();
CUST_DESC.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
CUST_DESC.ColumnName = "CUST_DESC";

dt.Columns.Add(CUST_ID);
dt.Columns.Add(CUST_DESC);
```

Most of the finds searching on MSDN and here has to do with delimited files.

Just looking to get pointed in the right direction.

Comment: This is simple file I/O and substring calls.  If you're looking for something fancier, use the [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in fixed width mode.

Comment: Thanks for the info on textfieldparser.  I think the substring method will work but this will be useful for another part of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're reading from the text File `f`:

```
string[] inputs = File.ReadAllLines(f);
foreach (String line in inputs) {

        String custAdd = line.Substring(20,27);
        //and do whatever you want with that string

}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was so close just didn't think about substring.  I'll vote this up when I get the rep.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Substring(6)

string.Substring(6, 12)
```